# Resource not found error in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

In web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.application.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In my Controller I am trying to get data using

```
$http.get(URI+"BoatAPI/fetchBoatingTypes").then(
function(response){
},function(response){   });
```

In my API class

```
@Path("BoatAPI") 
public class BoatAPI{
@GET 
@Path("fetchBoatingTypes")     
@Produces(MediaType.Application.JSON)
Public Response fetchBoatingTypes() throws Exception{
return response;  
}
```

and URI is   http://localhost:5555/HouseBoats/api/

when I am trying to fetch details in my page I am getting an error:

http://localhost:5555/HouseBoats/api/BoatAPI/fetchBoatingTypes 404 (not found).

Can you please explain why I am getting that error?

Comment: 404 not found error means your server code doesn't have any handler for this url...

Comment: In my API class @Produces(MediaType.Application_JSON) . while posting here I entered incorrectly. any one please tell me the reason why I am getting this eror?

Comment: can you explain it?

Comment: I don't have the whole page, but you can access this url from a browser, so as to check if it is served.

Comment: How exactly do you set the URLs prefix to `/HouseBoats/api/`? Check your  `web.xml` and `server.xml` (if your webserver is Tomcat) to make sure your path starts with what you're expecting. Also, what do you see when you open `http://localhost:5555/HouseBoats/api/` in browser?

Comment: Also, I assume you've provided not full code of your `fetchBoatingTypes` 
 method. If it's the full code then this code won't be compiled successfully. This would also explain why you can't access the API.

Comment: I am not able to paste my code here. But there is nothing to do with code inside API class. as it is not going inside fetchBoatingTypes method. In web.xml  I have given url pattern as <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>.

Comment: while executing http://localhost:5555/HouseBoats/api/ in my browser I am getting the message "requested resource not found".

Comment: var config={  
  "protocol" : "http",
  "port" : "5555",
  "domain" : "localhost",
  "project" : "HouseBoats"
}                                                                      



function getURI(){
 return config.protocol +"://"+ config.domain +":"+ config.port +"/"+ config.project +"/api/" ;
}

Comment: @akr you can edit your question to paste full code of the method. Do you register `BoatAPI` class somewhere in the application? Also, paste more of your web.xml, if possible.

Comment: I have edited my question